# Como escrever uma função recursiva?

Tags: c, arquivo, recursão

Recebi a tarefa de tornar esta função recursiva, mas não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.

```
int existe (int x){
    FILE *arq;
    int y;
    char buf[MAX];
    arq = fopen ("cliente.txt","r"); 
    fgets (buf,MAX,arq);
    while (!feof(arq)){
          y = atoi(strtok(buf,";"));
          if (x==y){
            fclose (arq);
            return 1;      
          }

        fgets (buf,MAX,arq);
    }
    fclose (arq);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Ela não pode ser recursiva, é possível usar recursão em parte dela. Mas aí entra a questão, pra que? Vai ganhar alguma coisa com isto? Fazer recursão por fazer não é um bom motivo. O principal motivo para fazer isto é quando é intuito fazer recurso. Se está com dificuldade para fazê-lo, então é porque não precisa. Sinceramente, neste caso eu nem perderia tempo em tentar fazer. É melhor fazer sem ser recursivo mesmo. O algoritmo parece sequência e não recursivo. Qualquer tentativa fará o algoritmo ficar pior.

Comment: @bigown: Não precisa ficar perguntando a utilidade... essa tarefa é claramente um exercício.

Comment: Isso é algum exercício? Quais os requisitos? Em outras palavras, que tarefa exatamente precisa ser recursiva? (a leitura e tratamento de um único token?)

Comment: Voltando ao assunto, o SOPT funciona melhor quando a sua pergunta é bem específica. O que você tentou até agora? Porque você acha que não dá pra resolver o problema? Sem mais detalhes a única coisa que podemos fazer é dar a resposta pronta e isso não tem graça :)

Comment: @hugomg mesmo que seja, é mau formulado. A minha resposta seria "é melhor deixar assim do que aprender fazer coisa errada".

Comment: A pergunta do OP está faltando detalhes mas discordo que esteja mal formulada. Quem passou a tarefa simplesmente quer ver se o OP sabe como substituir loops por recursão (isso é algo útil de saber, mesmo que o mais comum seja fazer essa conversão na direção oposta).

Comment: Pra mim o problema aqui é que eu não faço ideia do que essa função faz. Não está nada descritiva.

Comment: @Pablo. `cliente.txt` é um csv. A função em questão lê a primeira coluna em cada linha e vê se ela é  `x`, retornando 1 se encontrar `x` ou 0 caso contrário. Provavelmente o professor do Josh quer que ele reescreva o centro dessa lógica com uma função recursiva com casos de parada `EOF` e `x==y`. Bom, minha dica ficou maior do que a quantidade de código necessária para resolver esse exercício :).

Comment: `y = atoi(strtok(buf,";"));` faz exactamente o mesmo que `y = atoi(buf);` só que este último é bastante mais eficiente :-)

Answer (score 5):

O que se repete na função é o ciclo `while`

```
    while(!feof(arq)) {
        y = atoi(strtok(buf, ";"));
        if (x == y) {
            fclose(arq);
            return 1;
        }
        fgets(buf, MAX, arq);
    }
```

Portanto é isto, com ligeiras alterações, que é preciso substituir

```
int existe(int x) {
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("cliente.txt", "r");

    int value = existe_rec(x, arq);

    fclose(arq);
    return value;
}

int existe_rec(int x, FILE *arq) {
    char buf[MAX];
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, arq)) return 0;
    if (atoi(buf) == x) return 1; // strtok nao é necessário
    return existe_rec(x, arq);
}
```

**NB: falta validação de erros (que também não estava presente na versão original)!**

Answer (score 5):

Ao invés de oferecer o código-fonte pronto, que não ajuda em nada se você precisar escrever novas funções recursivas no futuro, vou dar dicas sobre **como implementar uma função recursiva**.

Qualquer função recursiva possui as 4 partes abaixo, implementadas nesta ordem:

1. Uma **decisão para continuar ou parar a execução** baseada em um dado de controle, avaliado através de uma expressão condicional. O dado de controle é normalmente passado para a função como parâmetro;
2. Um **corpo**, onde o trabalho  é feito.
3. Uma forma de **alterar o(s) dado(s) de controle**: as vezes alterando um contador, ou mais frequentemente alterando qual *nó* da estrutura é o *atual*;
4. Uma forma de fazer um **retrocesso no fluxo de execução** para voltar ao início: alcançado ao invocar a própria função novamente.

Por exemplo, a função a seguir imprime na tela (de forma recursiva) valores de `N` até **1**:

```
void countdown(int N)
{
    // 1 - Decisão para parar/continuar
    if (N < 1)
        return;

    // 2 - Corpo
    printf(“%d\n”, N);

    // 3 - Alterar o dado de controle
    N--;

    // 4 - Retrocesso no fluxo de execução
    countdown(N);    
}
```

Comment: Siga essas 4 regras sempre que precisar implementar **qualquer função recursiva**.

Comment: +1 quebrar o problema em partes e seguir este fluxo  é sucesso!